# How to save neural network model with .ckpt extension instead of.meta extnsion in tensorflow using python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and python. I am trying to save my trained neural network model with `.ckpt` extension. For that purpose, I have used code below:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            i =0;

            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

                i += batch_size

            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))
        saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

But this saves model with `.meta` extenssion. Can anyone help me save model with `.ckpt` extension?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine: you don't need to save the checkpoint with the `.ckpt` extension.

The `.ckpt` extension alone was used in the version 1 (V1) of the checkpoint files.
From Tensorflow `0.12` the checkpoint V1 can be read, but when you save a new checkpoint it will use the V2 format, where the name you choose is just a prefix for the `.meta` and `.index` files.

If you really need to write a `.ckpt` file you have to downgrade your Tensorflow installation to something `<0.12`